# dynamically adding an attribute to spring mvc form:hidden control

Tags: spring-mvc, hidden-field

i want to add the disabled attribute on the form:hidden tag dynamically when i go over a list of objects in my model. the code i have (that doesn't work) goes a little something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${myModel.myList}" var="obj">
        <div id="${obj.id}" onclick="selectObject(this);"><span>${obj.name}</span></div>
        <form:hidden path="myModel.selectedObj" />
</c:forEach>
```

i want the hidden input of obj in the list that his id is equal to the selectedObj to not be disabled, and every other hidden input i want to be disabled. This is what i tried:

```
<form:hidden path="myModel.selectedObj" <c:out value="${obj.id != myModel.selectedObj.id ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : ""}"></c:out> />
```

as i said, this didn't work out. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this piece of code:

```
<c:forEach items="${myModel.myList}" var="obj">
    <div id="${obj.id}" onclick="selectObject(this);"><span>${obj.name}</span></div>
    <c:if test="${obj.id eq myModel.selectedObj.id}">
        <form:hidden path="myModel.selectedObj" />
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${obj.id ne myModel.selectedObj.id}">
         <form:hidden path="myModel.selectedObj" disabled="disabled" />
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Or you can use a `<c:choose />` , with `<c:when />` and `<c:otherwise />` tags:

```
<c:forEach items="${myModel.myList}" var="obj">
    <div id="${obj.id}" onclick="selectObject(this);"><span>${obj.name}</span></div>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${obj.id eq myModel.selectedObj.id}">
            <form:hidden path="myModel.selectedObj" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <form:hidden path="myModel.selectedObj" disabled="disabled" />
        </otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested. The problem is that even when i wrote `<c:when test="${true}">
            <form:hidden path="myModel.selectedObj" disabled="disabled" />
        </c:when>`
The disabled attribute didn't render. It's like spring ignores attributes it doesn't know.

Comment: What version of spring are you using? Maybe [this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8661) bug is affecting you.

Comment: The version of my spring is 3.1.0.RELEASE so i don't think so. When i view the source i don't see the disabled attribute

Comment: Try not to use spring tags: `<input type="text" id="myModel.selectedObj" name="myModel.selectedObj" value="${formCommand.myModel.selectedObj} disabled="disabled" style="display:none" />`. Maybe spring ignores `disabled` attribute when using `form:hidden`.